# Does Snow Leopard provide Java 6 for 32-bit machines?

Tags: java, osx-snow-leopard, 32-bit

There has been [some speculation](http://2ality.blogspot.com/2009/08/32bit-java-6-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard.html) that Apple's Snow Leopard would finally include a version of Java 6 that works on 32-bit Intel hardware.  Now that the OS has been released, can anybody confirm whether or not this is the case?

If anybody here has installed Snow Leopard on a 32-bit machine, could you please run the following command and report the output?

> java -version

Comment: Thanks BTW. Learned something new tonight regarding the Java version command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a 32-bit only Mac and did a fresh install of Snow Leopard.  It is an original black MacBook (model 1,1).

Here is the output for 'java -version' which would be the default java version (as of initial Snow Leopard launch, 10.6.0):

```
java version "1.6.0_15"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_15-b03-219)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 14.1-b02-90, mixed mode)
```

Update: As of today, OS X 10.6.4 we have:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02-279-10M3065)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.3-b01-279, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Weird thing: I just updated one of my machines to 10.6.4 (directly from 10.6.0) and the java version is 10.6.0_15. Strange...

Answer (score 6):

I installed this morning. Looking in "Java Preferences", this is the info I have:

> Java SE 6 64 bit
>
> Java SE 6 32 bit

My machine is a 64 bit, but if the 32 bit version is available to me, I don't see why they would not make it available to people using 32 bit machines.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this [link](http://xandeuniz.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/believe-or-not-java-32-bits-on-snow-leopard/).

I needed Java 1.5 for  legacy app.

I've follow the instructions there and now I'm able to choose from:

[image]

The directory end up looking like this:

[image]

I not  sure  how trustworthy the JDK I've downloaded is, though. :(

Comment: Makes me wonder if an archived Leopard Java 5 (like one from a Time Machine backup) wouldn't work as well. Apple removed it from Snow Leopard for some unknown reason...

Comment: Probably they just didn't feel like supporting it. :(

Answer (score 1):

These versions are provided in the JavaVM Framework:

1.3.1 (1.3)

1.6.0 (1.5, 1.5.0, 1.6)

Comment: What does "About this Mac" report about your processor?

Comment: @Nerdling: Thanks, are you on a 32-bit machine?  If so, would you be kind enough to run the "java -version" command to verify that the 1.6 version actually runs on 32-bit hardware?

Comment: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

Answer (score 0):

I noticed as Cyberduck [has some trouble](http://trac.cyberduck.ch/ticket/3039), but indeed, on a first generation MacBook, 32 bit, Snow Leopard:

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/

total 48
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    5 Aug 29 11:24 1.3 -> 1.3.1
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 Jul 21 01:35 1.3.1
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Aug 29 11:24 1.5 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Aug 29 11:24 1.5.0 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    5 Aug 29 11:24 1.6 -> 1.6.0
drwxr-xr-x  8 root  wheel  272 Aug 29 11:55 1.6.0
drwxr-xr-x  9 root  wheel  306 Aug 29 11:55 A
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    1 Aug 29 11:24 Current -> A
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    3 Aug 29 11:24 CurrentJDK -> 1.6
```

(Not sure if I like SL deleting my previous Java SDKs, but well, it removed my printers as well...)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't update to Snow Leopard for any reason you can always use [this fix](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/static/soylatte/) to get 1.6.0 working on your 32-bit macbook... works pretty good for me. I'll upgrade to Snow Leopard once I have time to make a safe backup of HD

Comment: Thanks, I already have SoyLatte, but it's not the same.  It doesn't integrate with the native OS X desktop, it requires X11.